# WPF Get Selected Value from AutoComplete box

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

I have a AutoComplete box bound to a collection.  At different points need to get values from the selected item in the AuotComplete box.  The only way I could figure this out is like this;

```
 foreach (var x in myCollection)
        {
            if (myAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem == x)
            {
                myString = x.StringValue; 
                break;
            }
        }
```

This seems like a bad way of doing this, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem` stores the selected object item so you can use it directly, there is no need to iterate.

The common approach however is to separate the UI from your logic using the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dd419663.aspx). In this case, you'd bind the SelectedItem property to a property of your ViewModel class and access it whenever you need to use it in your logic.